# How to see TransformBlock name in Concurrency Visualizer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tpl-dataflow

What can I do to get Concurrency Visualizer to show Dataflow block names instead of the cryptic numbers, such as `block 47` below?

Here's the [MSDN link to DataflowBlockOptions.NameFormat Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604589%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Here's declaration of my TransformBlock:

```
     var myTransformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, double>(number => (double)number, 
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { NameFormat = "My Transform" });
```

Here's the message that I see in Events:

```
ProcessingInputMessages task launched from block 36 with 1 message(s) pending.
```

Of course, I would prefer to see:

```
ProcessingInputMessages task launched from Reader TransformBlock with 1 message(s) pending.
```

Here is what it looks like in Concurrency Visualizer:

[image]

Fine details:
This is a desktop application on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Visual Studio 2013 update 5, TPL Dataflow 4.5.25, Release mode, targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: NameFormat is the *format* for the name, not the name itself. Try adding the `{0}`and `{1}` to create a proper format string, From [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/Common.cs#L124) it looks that the name used for `{0}` is the type name. `{1}` is the ID as mentioned in the docs

Comment: In debug mode, I was able to see events such as `Block of type Reader type=TransformBlock_2 id=35 instantiated with Id 35.` and `Block of type Reader type=TransformBlock_2 id=831 instantiated with Id 831.` However, the `ProcessingInputMessages` and `OfferingOutputMessages` events still list blocks by their number.  At least, now I know what each number means...

Comment: I retested in Release mode, and i can see the same messages as in Debug mode.

Comment: Depending on the timeline selection, the block initialization messages might get filtered

Comment: As a workaround, I loaded up events into Excel.  There is a set of events that describes block number to name mapping.  I was able to use that to decipher the actual event messages.